# How to use Comparable as a Generic parameter in a Class

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have a home work in a data structures course, the question is:

---

Implementation of doubly-linked list class.

the methods:

- `display()`
- `length()` or `size()`
- `insertSorted(Comparable)`
- `insertToEnd(Comparable)`
- `insertToHead(Comparable)`
- `delete(Comparable)`
- `boolean search(Comparable)`

You must do this in JAVA

Create an application layer to test your class and its methods.
Compress all of your source files into a file and rename it as CS214HW1_first_lastName.zip Put your name in the filename. If needed, add a ReadMe.txt file for extra information such as compilation.

---

I implemented everything correctly  and the code is working fine, but I used for example: `insertSorted(int)` instead of `insertSorted(Comparable)`, because I didn't know how to do it.

I searched online, and read the JAVA documentation for (`Comparable`) but it is not enough :(

Can anybody help, please it is very important?

Here's some of my code, I can't write it all, cuz I don't want my friends to get the same code.

I will take zero if there is same code.

---

Code:

```
class DLL {    
    class Node {
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        int data;

        Node() {
            next = null;
            prev = null;
            data = 0;
        }

        Node(int dt) {
            next = null;
            prev = null;
            data = dt;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    void insertToHead(int dt) {    
        if (head == null) {    
            head = new Node(dt);    
        }    
        else {
            head.prev = new Node(dt);
            head.prev.next = head;
            head = head.prev;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        DLL dll = new DLL();

        dll.insertToHead(1);
        dll.insertToHead(2);
        dll.insertToHead(3);
    }
}
```

---

Please, somebody, tell me what to change in the beginning of the `class`.

1. are we gone use `extend`s or `implement`s `Comparable<E>` or what!
2. and what changes should i do the method `insertToHead(Comparable)`
3. what changes should i do to the `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably like to look into how [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) work as well.  The basic idea is that you would like to set up your class so that it will not know exactly the specific type of object but can be given some hint at the types of things it can expect of a declared generic type.

In your case, you would like to set up your list so that you can create linked lists of anything that can be compared.  Java has a `class` for that which you have mention called `Comparable<E>` this tells Java that it will be able to call such methods as `compareTo` on the provided object.

More specifically to your closing questions:

1. Use the following style of class declaration `MyClass<MyGenericType extends Comparable<MyGenericType>>`.  In your case `DLL<E extends Comparable<E>>`.
2. Switch the method arguments to accept `E` our declared generic type.
3. You should use the `class Integer` instead of the primitive type `int`, and change the creation of your list to `DLL<Integer> dll = new DLL<Integer>()`.

Fully updated version of provided code:

```
public class DLL<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    class Node {
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        E data;

        Node() {
            next = null;
            prev = null;
            data = null;
        }

        Node(E dt) {
            next = null;
            prev = null;
            data = dt;
        }
    }

    Node head;

    void insertToHead(E dt) {
        if (head == null) {    
            head = new Node(dt);
        }    
        else {
            head.prev = new Node(dt);
            head.prev.next = head;
            head = head.prev;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        DLL<Integer> dll = new DLL<Integer>();

        dll.insertToHead(1);
        dll.insertToHead(2);
        dll.insertToHead(3);
    }
}
```

This new implementation should provide a hint for how to proceed with some of the other homework tasks.  For instance you can now compare objects just by their [`compareTo` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) which might useful for sorting *hint hint*.

That doc page gives a very good explanation for how to use this method.  You should note that in their docs, they use a generic type called `T` instead of `E`, it really doesnt make a difference you can call it whatever you want provided it is unique to your program.

**Edit:**

An each hint in the sorting direction:

Ojbects which extend the `Comparable` class have a method which is called `compareTo` this method is set up so you can call:

```
object1.compareTo(object2);
```

this method returns an `int` which will be:

- `> 0` when object1 is greater than object2
- `= 0` when object1 is equal to object2
- `< 0` when object1 is less than object2

I don't want to give away too much as this is a homework assignment but here is my hint:

The way the above code sets up your classes, you would be able to tell the relationship between `NodeA` and `NodeB` by calling:

```
NodeA.data.compareTo(NodeB.data)
```

this will return an integer which gives your information according to the list above.

The `<=`,`>=`,`==` operators are likely found in the `Integer` class's `compareTo` method.

Something like:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int otherNumber = ((Integer) o).intValue();
    int thisNumber = this.intValue();
    if (otherNumber > thisNumber) {
        return 1;
    } else if (otherNumber < thisNumber) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but more likely they just do something like:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return this.intValue() - o.intValue(); // possibly normalized to 1, -1, 0
}
```

See the [Docs on `Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29) for more info on this.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!, i fully understood this, i understood it fast, cuz i know how Templates works in C++, but now i knew how it works in JAVA :), So Thank you..,

Comment: I have a question here: in Method insertSorted(Comparable) sorted means it arranging which one is bigger or not!, i mean this method works only if the method gets an integer parameter!, how can we specify that if i a condition in the method like this:

else if((head!=null) && (head.next==null) && (head.data<dt)){

it is not allowing the head.data<dt part !!, how can we solve this ?

Comment: You know this <=  >= operators works only with numbers !

Comment: @TarikSeyceri See my edit for info on your questions.

Comment: Woow!, it worked !!!!, you Rock!!, I can't Thank you enough man!, you saved my day ;) <3

Comment: for best results use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`